# How can I make dummy text (like \lipsum) grey?

Tags: color, overleaf, lipsum

I would like to make my dummy text more distinguishable from the normal text, so I can better determine the progress by making it for example grey?

Can I adjust the `\lipsum` command, so it applies this behavior every time I use the command?

Comment: Redefine `\lipsum` by adding `\color`?

Comment: It's rather easy to patch the `\lipsum` command to do so. Which version are you using? (The package had a major update last year.) You can use `\listfiles` to find out.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I included \listfiles in the beginning before \documentclass, but where would this output appear? I guess i have the newest version, i am using overleaf with this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-sigchi-extended-abstract-template/zzzfqvkmrfzn

Comment: @LeonD The output of `\listfiles` goes to the log file. You have to (if I'm not mistaken) click the “Logs” button, next to “compile” and then “View raw log”. But overleaf has TeXLive 2017 I think, which contains the older version of `lipsum`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In newer versions of `lipsum`, `\SetLipsumParListSurrounders` is being deprecated, so you can use `\setlipsum` instead:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsum{%
  par-before = \begingroup\color{gray},
  par-after = \endgroup
}
% or:
% \setlipsum{%
%   par-before = \colorlet{oldcolor}{.}\color{gray},
%   par-after = \color{oldcolor}
% }
\begin{document}

Hello

\lipsum[1-2]

Hello hello

\textcolor{red}{Hello again \lipsum[3] and again}

\end{document}
```

One of the versions above uses `\begingroup\color{gray}...\endgroup`, which may cause [issues with `wrapfig`](https://github.com/PhelypeOleinik/lipsum/issues/1).  The other version uses two `\color` commands, which may overflow the colour stack if used too often.

And for older versions of `lipsum`, which don't have `\SetLipsumParListSurrounders`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\lips@dolipsum{%
  \ifnum\value{lips@count}<\lips@max\relax
    \addtocounter{lips@count}{1}%
    \begingroup
      \color{gray}% <--- Change color here
      \csname lipsum@\romannumeral\c@lips@count\endcsname
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\lips@dolipsum
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello

\lipsum[1-2]

Hello hello

\textcolor{red}{Hello again \lipsum[3] and again}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works nice, thank you. Only sideeffect: \lipsum without the brackets gives me many paragraphs of dummy text, not only one, so i have to add [1] afterwards.

Comment: @LeonD It's not a side effect, but a feature of the package which exists even without this patch. If you don't say how many paragraphs you want the package defaults to `1-7`, so `\lipsum` gives the same as `\lipsum[1-7]`. You can change that with `\setlipsumdefault{1}`, for example, to give only the first paragraph or `\setlipsumdefault{1-3}` to give the first three.

Comment: Thanks for the really friendly and quick help!

Comment: @LeonD You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 10):

How about

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\SetLipsumParListSurrounders{\colorlet{oldcolor}{.}\color{gray}}{\color{oldcolor}}
\begin{document}
Hello

\lipsum[1-2]

Hello hello

\textcolor{red}{Hello again \lipsum[3] and again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: @egreg kindly pointed out a simpler solution:

```
\SetLipsumParListSurrounders{\begingroup\color{gray}}{\endgroup}
```

Apart from being simpler it also avoids overwriting `oldcolor` which some other macro might be using.

Comment: Nice, but [Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490992/how-can-i-make-dummy-text-like-lipsum-grey#comment1239752_490992) :/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oh, I didn't pay attention on this. ;-) In a few years it will work with overleaf, too, I suppose. ;-) (IMHO this reiterates [this concern](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8283/121799) if there is a problem, and if there is no problem there is no problem. ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't `\SetLipsumParListSurrounders{\begingroup\color{gray}}{\endgroup}` be simpler?

Comment: @egreg Probably it would, mille grazie!